# Swift Error Handling: "invalid pattern"

Tags: swift, error-handling, try-catch

I have a throwing static method on `CGPoint`:

```
extension CGPoint {
  static func cornerPointsForRegularPolygon(withSideCount sideCount: Int, center: CGPoint, cornerDistance distance: CGFloat) throws -> [CGPoint] {
    guard sideCount > 2 else {
      throw PolygonConstructionError.invalidSideCount(sideCount)
    }
    guard distance > 0 else {
      throw PolygonConstructionError.invalidCenterToCornerDistance(distance)
    }

    //...
  }
}
```

The type of error that is thrown by `cornerPointsForRegularPolygon` is:

```
extension CGPoint {
  enum PolygonConstructionError : ErrorProtocol {
    case invalidSideCount(Int)
    case invalidCenterToCornerDistance(CGFloat)
  }
}
```

I have written a test for `cornerPointsForRegularPolygon` which contains a try-catch pattern:

```
func testCornerPointsForRegularPolygon() {
  do {
    let _ = try CGPoint.cornerPointsForRegularPolygon(withSideCount: 0, center: CGPoint.zero, cornerDistance: 10)
  } catch CGPoint.PolygonConstructionError.invalidSideCount(let count) {
    XCTAssertEqual(count, 0)
  } catch {
    XCTFail("Should have thrown error `PolygonConstructionError.invalidSideCount`")
  }
}
```

I have used this kind of pattern many times before, but this time I'm getting an error - `Invalid pattern` - on `catch CGPoint.PolygonConstructionError.invalidSideCount(let count)`.

---

What is this supposed to mean, and how can I fix it?
Thanks :)

---

#### Update:

When I use the errors within `cornerPointsForRegularPolygon` I get the following:
[image: Errors]

Also I noticed that error types defined and thrown in extensions to existing types (like `CGPoint` and `UIBezierPath`) produce errors, while error types defined in my own types do not.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Your test cases compiles (and passes) for me.

Comment: As far as I tested, that error happens if the extension defining the enum is not included into the test target? Are you sure it actually is included in the test target?

Comment: @OOPer The enum is included in the target.